# Where can i find official scientific documents with table of PIDs for ECU

Tags: obd-ii, electronic-control-module, pid

I need an official document for reading information from PIDs that manage comunication with ECU of car.
I'm searching to sae.org and iso.org but i don't find nothing.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: generic obd2 pids are documented on the obd2 wiki and will probably point to the standard doc.  anything else (extended modes e.g. mode 23) is on a pay to know basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was looking into this some years ago (I didn't pursue it), I came up with this list of docs.  IDK if it's what you're looking for, but it's free.

- J1850:     network interface hdw, basic protocol, electrical specs, 
           & CRC byte, per J2178
- J1939:    trucks? CAN_bus; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J1939
- J1978:    minimal scan tool standards
- J1979:     1-byte PID's J2012:    DTC defs
- J2178:     2-byte PRN's ... Class B Data Communication Network Messages
- J1979:     emissions-related diagnostic msg hdr and data fields, per J2178 (?)
- J2190:     other diagnostic data fields, per J2178
- J2534:     API for reprogramming PCM

ISO ...

- 9141:    WP OBD: ISO 9142-2 primarily used in Chrysler, European, and 
          Asian vehicles
- 11898:   Road vehicles - Controller area network (CAN_bus).
- 14230:   Road vehicles - Diagnostic systems - Keyword Protocol 2000
- 15031    vehicle-to-external-equip comm foremissions-related dx's.  Same as J1979?
- 15765:   CAN_bus - support req'd after 2008 <-- *** --> maybe not 2004?

Comment: to iso.org and sae.org they aren't free...
But they are enought... did you know something regarding consumption?

Comment: @Dario Sorry - I meant my list was free.   I'm not clear what you mean by consumption.

Comment: some scientific documents that talk about "calculate consumption from ECU data"